# android picking images from gallery

Tags: android, bitmap, android-gallery

i am using a library for picking images from gallery and it is working , the problem is when i set the bitmap to the imageview it creates alot of duplicates in the gallery

here is the code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 11 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        ArrayList<Image> images = (ArrayList<Image>) ImagePicker.getImages(data);
        for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
            String s = images.get(i).getPath();
            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(s, bmOptions);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 200, 200, true);
                imagesUrl2.add(bitmap);
                uploadImages();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please show the uploadImages function code

Comment: i am using base64 encode , the problem was with the glide load , it creates many instance of the image

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with the glide loading from local uri ,it creates alot of instances in the gallery to get the image , so i passed the original uri of the images